# Opening in a new window from visualforce page opens a blank window?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to open standard page from a custom Visualforce Page  through javascript using command button.But it reacts differently each time.It works properly sometimes.But in some cases it opens a blank window.

```
    <apex:outputPanel id="jspanel"> 
        <script>  
        function onControllerReturn() {
     window.open('{!message}','_blank');   

        }
        </script>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:actionFunction name="doControllerSave"    action="{!merged}" 
     oncomplete="onControllerReturn()" rerender="jspanel" />

<apex:commandButton onclick="doControllerSave()" value="Merge" rerender="none" style="background:#D3D3D3;width:150px;" status="loadStatus"/>
```

Message contains URL Parameter to be passed.

Class:

```
public PageReference Merged() {
    update ac1;

    string mergeURL = ''; 
    mergelst = new List<String> (); 
    for(Account a:selectedAccounts){ 
        // mergeURL=a.id; 
        System.debug('size of accounts'+mergeURL); 
        account maxvalue=selectedAccounts.get(selectedAccounts.size() - 1); string
        nextvalue=maxvalue.id; 
        System.debug('lastaccountid'+nextvalue);
        mergeURL +='&cid='+a.Id; // mergelst.add(mergeURL);

    }


    try { 
        message ='/merge/accmergewizard.jsp?goNext=+Next+'+mergeURL ;
    } catch(Exception e)
    { 
        ApexPages.addMessages(e); message = 'Whoops! An error occurred -- ' + e.getMessage(); 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Need Suggestions.Urgent..

Comment: I would say that you need to examine all possible values of `message`. It's probably null or empty at some point.

Comment: You should do `window.open('{!JSENCODE(message)}','_blank');` instead of `window.open('{!message}','_blank');`; because code will break if the `message` contains any single quote(`'`);

Comment: This will open a window but won't show anything in that because the `message` contains an invalid URL `ApexPages.addMessages(e); message = 'Whoops! An error occurred -- ' + e.getMessage();`;

Answer (score 0):

message might get empty values sometimes. to get updated values on message variable. try this code.

Points to remember
1. script should be rerendered then you will get modified values from controller

```
<apex:outputpanel id="panel">
<script>
    function openNewWindow() {
        alert('{!url}');
    }
</script>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class SectionExtension {
    public String url {get;set;}

    public SectionExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        url = 'init val';
    }

    public Pagereference newWindow() {
        system.debug('##########');
        url = '/modified val';
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your command button remove Oncomplete attribute and addrerender tag

```
<apex:commandButton onclick="doControllerSave()" value="Merge" rerender="none" style="background:#D3D3D3;width:150px;" status="loadStatus"/>
```

Because sometimes it reload the page before `actionfunction` method so it will not work.

Comment: @ tushar,doing so gets back to the same page

Comment: @Pri Check in method if your variable has some value also check if you are getting any error in console.

Comment: I have updated my code of that method@tushar.When I debug it I am getting correctly

Comment: @Pri I think there is ome type here ` message ='/merge/accmergewizard.jsp?goNext=+Next+'+mergeURL` you have included `+Next+` in quote as well. Also would you share your updated VF page code.

Comment: I want that to open always when page redirects.thats why.

Comment: Updated Code in the sense?Entire page@tushar?

Comment: @Pri means you removed the oncomplete from `apex:commandbutton`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45790/discussion-between-pri-and-tushar-sharma).